# Select which jobject to load from argument

Tags: c#, .net, function, functional-programming

I feel this should be something I remember off the top of my head, but I can't think of a way to load the right data outside of dozens of `if` statements.

I have a bunch of files like this:

```
public static class TableDemo
{
    public static dynamic TableDef() { 
        var json = @"{
                    'date': {
                    'StartingPosition': 5,
                    'ColumnWidth': 7,
                    'DataType': 'Date'
                     };"

        dynamic newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
        dynamic TableJson = JObject.Parse(json);
        return TableJson;
   }
}
```

Each file describes a different flatfile I am loading. When I go to load it, I was hoping to use a standardized function to load everything into a datatable using an argument I pass in. This is my working example:

```
public static DataTable ParseTable()
{
   JObject data = TableDefinitions.TableDemo.TableDef();
   ... do stuff with data ...
}
```

I want to be able to pass in an argument like this:

```
public static DataTable ParseTable(string LoadTable)
{
   JObject data = TableDefinitions.LoadTable.TableDef();
   ... do stuff with data ...
}
```

Calling the function using something like:

```
ParseTable("Users");
```

Since I will have hundreds of files, how do I do that without a ton of `if` statements like this:

```
if(LoadTable =="Users"){
       JObject data = TableDefinitions.Users.TableDef();
}else if(LoadTable =="Employees"){
       JObject data = TableDefinitions.Employees.TableDef();
}
```

Comment: You can simplify the `if` statements using a `Dictionary<string, JObject>` where the key is the table ("`Users`", "`Employees`", ...) and the value is the correspondent `JObject` (`TableDefinitions.Users.TableDef()`, etc)

Comment: I don't know you scenario, but are you sure, you're not reinventing what JsonConvert<OjectType>.Deserialize() does?

Comment: @ChristophLütjen I have used  `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(jsonString)` but I will look into your way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be solved using reflection.

Your code should probably look something like this:

```
interface ITableDef
{
    JObject TableDef();
}

class UserCollection : ITableDef
{
   // Stuff
   public JObject TableDef(){ // Todo }
}

class EmployeeCollection : ITableDef
{
   // Stuff
   public JObject TableDef(){ // Todo }
}

class TableDefinitions
{
  public UserCollection Users {get;set;}
  public EmployeeCollection Employees {get;set;}
  // Stuff
}

public JObject RunTableDefMethod(TableDefinitions tableDefinitionsInstance, string propertyName)
{
    var propInfo = typeof(TableDefinitions).GetProperty(propertyName); // you can cache this
    var instance = propInfo.GetValue(tableDefinitionsInstance) as ITableDef;
    return instance.TableDef();
}
```

Comment: This looks promising, but RunTableDefMethod needs to return the JObject so I can use it externally. I tried switching the return type, but then not sure how to call it. `RunTableDefMethod(Users, "TableDef")` doesn't work

Comment: `var jobj = RunTableDefMethod(TableDefinitions, "Users");`

Comment: @AmirPopovich you need to change your `RunTableDefMethod` to return an instance of `JObject`